# Telerik MVC Grid Server side row template not rendering

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am trying to make a MVC Telerik grid with a custom row template.
But I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I just don't get my template rendered

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grid")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 750px" })
    .RowTemplate(@<text>
    <div>Product Name: @item.ItemName </div>
    <div>
        hsdjshdjshjdh
    </div>
    </text>).Pageable(pager=> pager.PreviousNext(true).Numeric(false))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(1)
                         .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllItems", "ItemDetail"))
            )
)
```

Am I missing something important ?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Kendo Grid then it is RowTemplate**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PutYourModelHere>()
    .Name("grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 750px;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(e =>{}).ClientTemplate("").Width(140).Title("Item Name");

    })
    .RowTemplate(
        "<tr data-uid='#: uid #'>" +
            "<td>" +
                "#: ItemName #" +
            "</td>" +
          "</tr>"     
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllItems", "ItemDetail"))
    )        
    .Scrollable()
)
```

Comment: I need to use server side controls as row template. ClientRowTeplate() can use only client side controls.

Comment: RowTemplate() for Server side controls.  Take a look at this http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-row-template.html